# Need help with .sh script

Tags: tor, execute-command, .sh

I’m trying to get this `~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/ && ./start-tor-browser` to run as a .sh. I've tried over and over again to get it to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash 
chmod +x file.command ~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/ && ./start-tor-browser
```

It has execute permissions and is saved as an .sh.

Comment: Have you added `#!/bin/sh` as the very first line of your script?

Comment: yes, but its  `#!bin/bash` and it has a line between it and my code.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` tells the script to run in the bash shell and not the sh shell.  Change it to `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: I changed bash to sh, didnt work.

Comment: So that would look like  `sudo #!/bin/sh 
chmod +x file.command ~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/ && ./start-tor-browser` ?

Comment: Where is the `./start-tor-browser`?  Is that located in the `~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/` folder?  if so, your script should be `#!/bin/sh` as the first line.  And `cd ~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/ && ./start-tor-browser` as the second line.

Comment: No, you need to run `chmod  +x <filename>` as a separate command after you save the file

Comment: so i need to save the file with `#!/bin/sh chmod +x file.command ~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/ && ./start-tor-browser` and create an new .sh that says `chmod +x <filename>`?

Comment: `chmod +x` sets the executable bit for a file.  `./start-tor-browser` is the command to start whatever that is.  `chmod +x` is not needed in a script, as it does not need to set the bit every single time you run it.  I am assuming that `~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/` is the folder on the desktop where `start-tor-browser` exists?

Comment: yes, that were it is. And yes, `#!/bin/sh` as the first line and `cd ~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/ && ./start-tor-browser` as the second line.

Comment: I'm going to write an answer with a way to create a script that will work for this.

Comment: No, i dont think so. It works in the console without root, it does need cd though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo nano /bin/start-tor
```

and copy/paste this into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit and then execute the following commands in an open terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x /bin/start-tor
```

To run the script, open a terminal and run:

```
start-tor &
```

This file is already chmod +x when downloaded.so there is no need to do all that.

Comment: @ShonnAlves then erase all that stuff re-download it and extract the file again

Comment: @ShonnAlves I edited the answer to be more thorough and I just tested this and it works just fine for me

Comment: @ShonnAlves in the future, you would've just needed to run `chmod +x ~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser` if you want to make that file executable. I think they confused you with the whole file.command thing it probably should have read `<filename>` or something like that instead so you would have known to substitute something else there. ohwhell glad to help!

Comment: For future reference,  will "cd"work in nano mode? Forgive me for my apparent ignorance.

Comment: @ShonnAlves you could've used `cd /bin` first, and then `sudo nano start-tor` instead

Comment: @ShonnAlves sorry I edited that last response

Comment: @ShonnAlves or, if you just wanted to run the tor browser from the terminal without nano you could run `cd ~/Desktop/Tor/tor-browser_en-US` and then `./start-tor-browser`